# Error inside a while loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with this code:

```
var = 1
while var :
  if(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'sometext')]")):
    var = 1
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(2)
  else:
    mail = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email_l']")));
    mail.send_keys(mailStr)
```

So the problem is inside the if, in fact in the site there isn't the text sometext, but I want continue with the else condition. 
The error is as follows:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(),'sometext')]"}
```

and it stops. 
which is my error? 
thanks

Comment: Your indentation is wrong

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: You've corrected the indentation, but still you need to provide a more thorough explanation so your question would be clearer. Additionally, there is no way to debug Selenium without access to the HTML code.

Comment: I don't understand independently from the html code, why when I run the code it can't go on and give me the error. I think that if the condition inside the if is false, the program should go inside the else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//p[contains(text(),'sometext')]"}
```

...implies that the *Locator Strategy* doesn't identifies any unique element within the [**HTML DOM**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

As per your question that within the webpage there no element exists with text as **sometext** and you want continue with the else condition. So, you need to put the `if{}` block surrounded by a `try-catch {}` block and transfer the code block within `else{}` block within the `catch{}` block as follows:

```
var = 1
while var :
    try:
        if(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'sometext')]")):
            var = 1
            browser.refresh()
            time.sleep(2)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        mail = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email_l']")));
        mail.send_keys(mailStr)
```